# Centered \paragraph section with line break

Tags: koma-script

I tried the following code for getting a line break:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommands[afterskip=1sp]{paragraph,subparagraph}
```

However, I don’t have any idea how to get the paragraph centered. I tried \centering already, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand what you want to do. If the headings of all section levels should be centered, redefine `\raggedsection`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  afterskip=1sp,
  beforeskip=-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex
]{paragraph,subparagraph}

\renewcommand*\raggedsection{\centering}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

If only paragraph and subparagraph headings should be centered (I do not recommennd this), redefine `\sectionlinesformat`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  afterskip=1sp,
  beforeskip=-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex
]{paragraph,subparagraph}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{paragraph}{\centering#3#4}{%
    \ifstr{#1}{subparagraph}{\centering#3#4}{%
      \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}%
}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\subparagraph{Test}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that’s what I was looking for. I was going for the latter option, but as you don’t recommend it, I might change my mind.